# How to associate file number with coordinate information in a matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, coordinates, raster

I have a image `raster` of dimensions width = 155 and height = 175. Each pixel coordinate is associated with a number, meaning `(1,1)` is `1`, `(1,155)` is 155 and `(175,155)` is 27125. Given a number, how can I find the coordinate `(x,y)`? I am working in `Java`.

**Smaller matrix width = 3 height = 4**

```
1      2      3         
1,1   1,2   1,3    

4      5      6
2,1   2,2    2,3

7      8      9
3,1   3,2    3,3

10    11     12
4,1   4,2   4,3
```

Comment: `int number = ... ; row = number / 155; col = number % 155;`. Btw: arrays are zero-based, therefore it should be `(0, 0)` corresponds to `0`, `(0, 154)` corresponds to `154` and so on. If you, for any reason, need 1-base d indexing, you may need to add `1` to both coordinates in the computation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
private int X_SIZE = 155;


public int getX(int position) {
    return position % X_SIZE;   // Starts from 0
}

public int getY(int position) {
    return position / X_SIZE;   // starts from 0
}
```

Where 155 is the dimension of the x size.

Imagine to have a matrix 3 x 5. `X_SIZE` is 3.

Here is the matrix population

```
      X
  Y   0      1      2
     ----------------
  0 | 0      1      2

  1 | 3      4      5

  2 | 6      7      8

  3 | 9     10     11

  4 |12     13     14
```

And here are some values:

```
  getX(0) = 0 % 3 = 0
  getY(0) = 0 / 3 = 0

  getX(1) = 1 % 3 = 1
  getY(1) = 1 / 3 = 0 

  getX(8) = 8 % 3 = 2
  getY(8) = 8 / 3 = 2 

  getX(12) = 12 % 3 = 0
  getY(12) = 12 / 3 = 4
```

---

This work is you use a 0 based x and y calculation and starts from 0 to populate the array.

To have a 1 based for x and y and starting from 1 to populate the array you need to change the functions as follow:

```
 private int X_SIZE = 155;


 public int getX(int position) {
     return (position - 1) % X_SIZE + 1;   // Starts from 1
 }

 public int getY(int position) {
     return (position - 1) / X_SIZE + 1;   // starts from 1
 }
```

Here are the same example as before:

```
      X
  Y   1      2      3
     ----------------
  1 | 1      2      3

  2 | 4      5      6

  3 | 7      8      9

  4 |10     11     12

  5 |13     14     15
```

And here are some values:

```
  getX(1) = (1 - 1) % 3 + 1 = 1
  getY(1) = (1 - 1) / 3 + 1 = 1

  getX(2) = (2 - 1) % 3 + 1 = 2
  getY(2) = (2 - 1) / 3 + 1 = 1 

  getX(9) = (9 - 1) % 3 + 1 = 3
  getY(9) = (9 - 1) / 3 + 1 = 3 

  getX(13) = (13 - 1) % 3 + 1 = 1
  getY(13) = (13 - 1) / 3 + 1 = 5
```

Comment: Tried it. So, when I use position = 157, the coordinates are `(1,157)` (starting from 0), whereas they should be (2,2), if I start with `1` rather than `0`. How should I correct this?

Comment: Check if the by dimensional array is a square or a rectangle. Or invert getX with getY

Comment: Unfortunately, I still do not get the right coordinate values. I have added a small matrix and the coordinates which I would like to display for a specific value.

Comment: @novicegeek check now, I added the example also for 1 based arrays.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you :)